# JS - Find greatest integer less than or equal to a given bound that's divisible by a certain number

Tags: javascript, math

This may be more of a maths question, but I need a JS way of finding the highest whole number not larger than a bound that is evenly-divisible by another number.

I have a calculateMaxDividends function, which takes two Number parameters, 'dividends' and 'shares'.

So I need to find the maximum dividends value that can be evenly-distributed amongst the number of shares.

Example: dividends = 1000, shares = 100. Would give 1000, because 1000 is evenly-divisible by 100.

Another example: dividends = 75, shares = 20 would give 60, because 60 is evenly divisible by 20, and the next such number (80) is greater than the bound of 75.

How would I calculate something like this in JS?

Comment: What would your expected result be if you had e.g. `dividends=1000` and `shares=98`?

Comment: I don't know, that's the problem.

Comment: I'm only asking because I don't understand the question as stated. I mean saying "the highest whole number evenly divisible by another number" doesn't make sense. The highest number doesn't exist because there's infinite numbers divisible by a number

Comment: Is dividends an array of numbers?

Comment: Andreas: This is why I said it may be more of a maths question, because I don't know the equation

Comment: Do you mean the highest number that's less than `dividends` and divisible by shares?

Comment: @apokryfos That seems to be exactly it (except given his example, he wants less than or equal to rather than strictly less than). I edited the question to make that clear.

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a really simple thing to do using the modulo operator!

Here's a little snippet:

```js
let dividends = 136531;
let shares = 93;
let maximumPortion = dividends - (dividends % shares);
console.log(maximumPortion);
```

What this does is take your dividends and divide it by shares and find the remainder, and it then subtracts the remainder (which doesn't fit into the division evenly) from the number you started with to return the maximum portion

As a concise body arrow function given the provided function name:

```js
const calculateMaxDividends = (dividends, shares) => dividends - (dividends % shares);
```

Thanks for your question!